# Eliminar una funcion o vaciar su contenido

Tags: javascript, function

```
if ( window.innerWidth < 500 ) {
  lalo() 
} else {
  //aqui destruir funcion lalo
  lalo2() //ejecuta una nueva funcion
}
```

En resumen lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el ancho de mi navegador sea menor a 500px se ejecute una funcion, pero cuando sea mayor, se elimine esa funcion o su contenido se vacíe..Necesito esto para que no interfiera con la otra funcion que se va a ejcutar cuando el ancho del navegador sea mayor a 500. QUe las dos funciones corran juntas crea un conflicto.

Comment: No queda claro lo que buscas, con un simple if podes hacer que el funcionamiento para las distintas resoluciones no se pise

Comment: cuando la resolucion es menor a 500 en mi web se crea un menu vertical para movil, pero cuando es mayor a 500 se crea otro menu horizontal. El problema es que cuando se crea un menu no se quita el otro. Yo podria quitarlo poniendo en el ELSE un REMOVE al elemento, pero el tema es que tengo MUCHAS animaciones y efectos y cosas, y seria muy pesado remover una por una, entonces prefiero desactivar toda la funcion que encierra mis animaciones, y asi ahorrame todo el trabajo al desactivar todo el contenido de la funcion

Comment: Solo debes poner el if ( window.innerWidth < 500 ) {
  lalo();
} si es mayor que haga nada :v

Comment: Se seguiria ejecutando la funcion "lalo()"..y yo no quiero que se ejecute cuando pase los 500. Porque esa funcion me crea un menu para movil... y cuando este en una resolucion mayor a 500 me aparecera otro menu para laptop, pero ademas seguira el menu para movil..por eso debo eliminar la funcion anterior